# expect + how to identify if expect break because time out?

Tags: linux, shell, tcl, ksh, expect

The target of the following simple expect script is to get the **hostname** name on the remote machine

Sometimes expect script fail to perform ssh to $IP_ADDRESS ( because remote machine not active , etc )

so in this case the expect script will break after 10 second (timeout 10) , this is OK but......

There are two options

1. Expect script perform ssh successfully , and performed the command hostname on the remote machine
2. Expect script break because timeout was 10 seconds

On both cases expect will exit

- in case of ssh successfully expect will break after 0.5-1 second but in case of bad ssh then it will break after 10 seconds

but I don’t know if expect script perform ssh successfully or not?

is it possible to identify timeout process ? or to verify that expect ended because timeout?

Remark my Linux machine version  - red-hat 5.1

**Expect script**

```
 [TestLinux]# get_host_name_on_remote_machine=`cat << EOF
  > set timeout 10
  > spawn  ssh   $IP_ADDRESS
  >            expect {
  >                      ")?"   { send "yes\r"  ; exp_continue  }
  > 
  >                      word:  {send $PASS\r}
  >                   }
  > expect >  {send "hostname\r"}
  > expect >    {send exit\r}
  > expect eof
  > EOF`
```

**Example in case we not have connection to the remote host**

```
 [TestLinux]# expect -c  "$get_host_name_on_remote_machine"
 spawn ssh 10.17.180.23
 [TestLinux]# echo $?
 0
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To do sensible things on timeout, you need to tell expect what should happen:

```
set timeout 10
expect {
    ")?"     { send "yes\r"  ; exp_continue  }
    "word:"  { send "$PASS\r"                }
    timeout  { puts "timed out during login"; exit 1 }
}
set timeout -1   ; # Infinite...
expect ">"   { send "hostname\r"             }
expect ">"   { send "exit\r"                 }
expect eof
exit
```

Notice above how I use `exit 1` when I hit an error. Your shell will be able to pick that up through `$?`, etc. (Without the `1` argument, the `exit` command will cause the script to terminate “successfully”; the same happens if you drop off the bottom of the script.)

Answer (score 4):

Not really answering the original question, but why are you talking to SSH interactively when you just can pass it a script to execute? It's a shell after all.

I mean, just run:

```
ssh user@host '/usr/bin/hostname'
```

and ssh will spawn the `hostname` command remotely and connect its stdout to the stdout of the process which spawned `ssh`.

Back to the point—[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136554/timeout-doesnt-work-with-re-flag-in-expect-script) looks like an example on how to bind an action to a timeout condition.

Comment: @Eytan, I did not talk about supplying a password: the usage of Expect for this is sensible. I was just puzzled by the following interactive talking with ssh.

Comment: I need to enter the password ( I can’t set ssh keys ) , each machine have diff password so the target of this expect script is to ssh to each linux machine and enter the relevant password , any way thx , but I need to find solution - how to verify timeout from expect script

Comment: @Eytan, I provided you with a link to a working example dealing with the timeout condition--what's the problem?

Comment: Not sure how to set my expect according to link example , -:(

Comment: @Eytan, isn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/136788/720999) a complete example of how to expect something which can time out?